# matrix calculus with types (similar to matrixcalculus.org)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

Is it possible to do matrix calculus in Mathematica, like in http://www.matrixcalculus.org/ ?

One of the main limitations I've found in Mathematica is that symbols are assumed to be scalars by default. I'm not aware of any mechanism to declare a symbol `x` in Mathematica and say "the type of `x` is an m x n matrix". Whenever I want to do something like that I have to construct an explicit matrix for a fixed number of rows and columns, using `Table` or `Array`. Then, I can differentiate with respect to individual scalars, but I'm not aware of any method to get general vector and matrix derivatives as in matrixcalculus.org, using Mathematica.

EDIT: There is a way to express that a symbol is a matrix. For example:

```
$Assumptions = {
   Element[A, Matrices[{m, n}]],
   Element[B, Matrices[{n, k}]]
};
```

However differentiation still doesn't work:

`D[A.B, A]` doesn't return the correct answer `Transpose[B]`

Comment: good question, but I really think this is duplicate `For instance, is there some way I can say "let A and B be arbitrary real m×n and k×m matrices`  from the linked to question.

Comment: What about things like `D[(A + t X).B.(A + t X), t] /. t -> 0`?

Comment: so... is the answer to my question "no, Mathematica can't do it" ?